# Select customers who purchased BOTH this year and last

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm fairly new to SQL and I'm using BigQuery to find customers who purchased in 2019 and 2018.

This is the query I'm using to find the customers who purchased in 2019.

```
SELECT DISTINCT contact_email
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS instance
  FROM `table.orders`
) orders -- identify duplicate rows
WHERE 
    instance = 1 
    AND processed_at between '2019-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' AND '2020-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'
```

I'm struggling now with how to pull in distinct users who purchased this year AND last year. Can anyone point me in the correct direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm.  I think I might do this as an aggregation query:

```
select o.contact_email
from `table.orders o`
where instance = 1 and
      processed_at >= timestamp('2018-01-01') and
      processed_at < timestamp('2020-01-01')
group by o.contact_email
having count(distinct year(processed_at)) = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select contact_email
from `table.orders`
where 
    instance = 1
    and processed_at >= timestamp('2018-01-01')
    and processed_at <  timestamp('2020-01-01')
group by contact_email
having
    max(case 
        when processed_at >= timestamp('2019-01-01')
        and  processed_at <  timestamp('2020-01-01')
        then 1 end
    ) = 1
    and max(case 
        when processed_at >= timestamp('2018-01-01')
        and  processed_at <  timestamp('2019-01-01')
        then 1 end
    ) = 1
```